# Date variable incorrectly converted into a numeric variable following the conversion of the data frame from a long format to a wide format

Tags: r, data.table

I am working with a data frame that consists of participants' data across multiple timepoints. I am attempting to convert the data frame from a long format to a wide format. The data frame consists of variables belonging to different data types such as date and numerics.

```
library(data.table)

SN <- c("AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "DDD")
Timepoint <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2)
date <- c("31-Mar-17", "08-Mar-17", "31-Mar-18", "28-Mar-18", "17-Mar-17", "26-Feb-18", "07-Apr-18")
score <- c(13, 16, 17, 9, 14, 15, 15)
age <- c(12, 15, 16, 9, 14, 14, 15)
df <- data.frame(SN, Timepoint, date, score, age)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%d-%B-%y")
```

I used the following code to convert the data from a long format to a wide format:

```
df2 <- dcast(melt(df, id.vars = c("SN", "Timepoint")),
         SN ~ Timepoint + variable, value.var = "value")
```

As R interprets all variables to belong to a common type (numeric), the date variable has been incorrectly converted to a numeric variable.

The following is the incorrect output I have obtained:

[image: Incorrect Output]

The correct output which I am trying to achieve is as follow:

[image: Correct Output]

Thanks! Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may need to have 'date' also in the `id.vars` as the 'value' column in `numeric` and by mixing two classes, it converts to a single one i.e the numeric one.  Instead, if we have two separate columns and make use of the `value.var` from `data.table::dcast` (takes more than one variable)

```
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.vars = c("SN", "Timepoint", "date")),
      SN ~ Timepoint + variable, value.var = c("date", "value"))
```

---

Based on the expected output, we may only need `dcast`

```
dcast(setDT(df)[], SN ~ Timepoint, value.var = c('date', 'score', 'age'))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried including setDT and without setDT. Both provides me with the same correct result. May I know why did you incorporate setDT into the code?

Comment: @DTYK By doing that, it will use the `melt/dcast` from `data.table` instead of the `reshape2` (if both packages are loaded), but you can also specify with `data.table::dcast`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is by converting the date variables to a date after the data is restructured, instead of before.  The dplyr package makes it easy to change all columns based on the name, such as columns that end with date.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

SN <- c("AAA", "BBB", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE", "DDD")
Timepoint <- c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2)
date <- c("31-Mar-17", "08-Mar-17", "31-Mar-18", "28-Mar-18", "17-Mar-17", "26-Feb-18", "07-Apr-18")
score <- c(13, 16, 17, 9, 14, 15, 15)
age <- c(12, 15, 16, 9, 14, 14, 15)
df <- data.frame(SN, Timepoint, date, score, age)
df2 <- dcast(melt(df, id.vars = c("SN", "Timepoint")),
             SN ~ Timepoint + variable, value.var = "value") %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(ends_with("date")), as.Date, format = "%d-%B-%y")
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate method to solve the problem!